# Deleting Service worker cache crashes

Tags: javascript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have added the following (sample) code to my app (Angular app, is true for any JS app) to delete the serviceworker cache:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    if ('caches' in window) {
        caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
                return caches.delete(key);
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

But I frequently receive crash reports with the following error for some users using Chrome 72 and above for Windows:

`TypeError · undefined is not a function`

for function

`caches.keys`

Anyone has any idea why this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

The [keys method is only found on Cache objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys).

You can obtain cache objects from the [`cache.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/open) function.

Example usage:

```js
caches.open(name).then(function(cache) {
  cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
    //Do something with keys
  });
})
```

Comment: Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/keys#Syntax

Comment: I see. I'm sorry i misunderstood you. Perhaps you need to open a cache first before getting keys?